# Fixtures with associations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixtures

i am getting some problem in Fixtures

I am having models advantage and kind

advantage.rb

```
belongs_to :kind
```

kind.rb

```
 has_many :advantages
```

advantages.yml

1.

```
id: 1
title: something
kind: apple
kind_id: 1
```

2.

```
id: 2
title: somethjin
kind: orange
kind_id: 2
```

kinds.yml

```
apple:
  id: 1
  name: apple
orange:
  id: 2
  name: orange
```

I am trying to bring association here as kind_id is coming with some junk values

so i did like

kinds.yml

```
apple:
  name: apple
orange:
  name: orange
```

and in advantages.yml

something:

```
title: something
kind: apple
```

somethjin

```
title: somethjin
kind: orange
```

But it didn't work

How to resolve this

Answer (score 1):

Try like this but not sure:

```
kinds.yml
 apple:
  id: 1
  name: 'name1'
 orange:
  id: 2
  name: 'name2'

advantages.yml
 adv1:
  id: 1
  title: 'title1'
  kind: apple
```

Comment: Rail 4 Tip: When you specify your own ID for a fixture record Rails won't let you refer to that record by its label.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an answer for your question. But i always use Factories instead of fixtures. It is much easier to maintain and associations are easy.

Take a look here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl

Comment: Factories are not a holy grail of preparing data for tests. Both solutions have their uses.